# what does map! do in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm fairly new to ruby and I'm a bit confused by what the `map!` syntax does. I see the following line on the codebase

```
b.map(&:values).uniq!.map!
```

`b.map(&:values).uniq!` gives me the following output:

```
[["us"],
 ["au"],
 ["fr"],
 ["mx"],
 ["ad",
  "ae",
  "af",
  "al",
  "am",
  "ao",
  "aq"]]
```

When I add a `.map!` to the end of `b.map(&:values).uniq!` I get `#<Enumerator: ...>`. I'm not really sure what is happening. If anyone could explain to me what is going on that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-map-21):

> Invokes the given block once for each element of `self`, replacing the element with the value returned by the block.
>
> See also `Enumerable#collect`.
>
> **If no block is given, an Enumerator is returned instead.**

This means that if you have used `map!` with a block - the array would have replaced all its elements with the return value of the block:

```
b.map(&:values).uniq!.map!(&:first)
# => ["us", "au", "fr", "mx", "ad"]
```

Since you did not add a block, you got an [`Enumerator`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerator.html), which is like a delayed action cursor, where you can add your block later on:

```
enum = b.map(&:values).uniq!.map!
enum.each(&:first)
# => ["us", "au", "fr", "mx", "ad"]
```

Comment: so what is the Enumerator?

Comment: check out this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973624/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-enumerator-class-in-ruby